# Stylus(+gulp?) and cache busting for images

Tags: css, caching, gulp, stylus

How do you implement cache busting for images in stylus?

It should transform urls like this:

`background: url(my.png) -> url(my-a1b2c3.png)`

There is a function `url` in stylus options, which may help here, but is there a well-known implementation for that?

The task seems to be quite common.

What would be a good solution?

P.S. Right now I'm using this function for `url` (manifest.json has renamings):

```
let resolve = stylus.resolver();
let manifest;
if (!isDevelopment) {
  manifest = require('./manifest/assets.json');
}

function url(urlLiteral) {
  urlLiteral = resolve.call(this, urlLiteral);
  for (let asset in manifest) {
    if (urlLiteral.val == `url("${asset}")`) {
      urlLiteral.string = urlLiteral.val = `url("${manifest[asset]}")`;
    }
  }
  return urlLiteral;
}
```